# ML algorithm to create an optimal photo portfolio

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, constrained-optimization

I would like to train an ML algorithm that would help create a best subset of 3 photos from a set of N photos. I'm wondering what kind of model could be used for this kind of portfolio/deck optimization problem.

For each photo, I have two metadata:

- Photo quality rating
- Photo type (e.g. "food", "animal", "scenery")

In the training data, I have sets of 3 photos along with their binary user ratings: "Like" or "Dislike". It is assumed that users took into account both photo scores & type diversity when liking or disliking.

Given these parameters, what kind of modeling approach could I employ that given a set of photos, can help pick the best three (i.e. maximize the chance of a user "Like"), taking into account photo quality & photo type diversity?

Interested in an approach that would be compute efficient.

Comment: As a starting point, the simplest "model" just takes the top 3 photos with different types. There will be some corner cases where this doesn't do well (a fashion photographer won't have many high-quality photos of food), but there's little a machine learning algorithm could do in that case.

Comment: How would a model pick the types and make trade offs for type diversity vs photo quality? It's kind of like a portfolio or card deck optimization problem. I'm familiar with regression and classification problems, but not sure how to fit this kind of problem into a ML modeling framework

Comment: I'm not sure that it's a machine learning problem as much as an optimization problem. The nature of the trade-off depends on how you specify the objective function to trade photo quality for diversity. Basically, you're solving an optimization problem with a constraint (only three photos).